# How to loop and set the value of 2nd Span in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a query in which i want to set the value of second span in the div.

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <span>This is the first span</span>
    <span>This is the second span</span>
    <span>This is the 3rd span</span>
    </div>
```

I am using following javascript.

```
function SetValue(myValue) {

            var mainDiv = document.getElementById("content");
            for(var i=0;i<mainDiv.childNodes.length;i++) {
               if(mainDiv.childNodes[i] == 2) {
                   mainDiv.childNodes[i].innerText = myValue;
               }


            }
        }
```

i want to get the parameter value to be set in second span of the main div

Comment: Is the code you posted not working? What's your question?

Comment: @MoizKachwala: There's no reason for a loop, and you'd need to use `.children` instead of `.childNodes`, and `.textContent` instead of `.innerText` for most browsers. `var span = document.getElementById("content").children[2]; span.textContent = span.innerText = myValue;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this pure JS implementation, since there is no indication, besides the tag, that JQuery is an option and it is totally not needed for something like this:

```
function SetValue(myValue){
    document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("span")[1].innerText = myValue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MTSAN/1/

Answer (score 2):

Inside `SetValue`, use this one line:

`$("#content span:eq(1)").html(myValue);`

Don't need the loop or any of that other stuff.

Docs on [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Fiddle of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/dB5vS/3/

Comment: i have one query and i want to go through by looping the elements in child.

Comment: @Gromer: The fiddle shows that it doesn't work. You're targeting the wrong span. [Here's an update](http://jsfiddle.net/dB5vS/1/) that makes it a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

simply use .eq() function

```
$('#content').find('span').eq(1).text("Your Value");
```

.eq function starts from index 0;

Here is the **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/n9HLU/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement will have to check `mainDiv.childNodes[i].tagName == "span"` and increment a counter, setting the innerText once it has found the second .  Alternatively (and better, in my opinion) several jQuery suggestions using nth-child css selectors have been posted.

Comment: * once it has found the second <span>

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```
$(function() {
  $('#content span:nth-child(2)').text('your text');
});​
```